# symfony/doctrine special query (MAX) with Doctrine_Query::create()

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I am trying to add a new query to my app and I'm stuck a bit. I also don't really know what to use as search term, so I'm stuck.

Ok, let's get into it right now:

```
Table: a
primary key: id
string: name

Table: b
primary key: id
foreign key: a_id
int: cluster
```

What I want to do is retrieve the max cluster int for a given object a. In SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(b.cluster) FROM b WHERE b.a_id = ? GROUP BY b.cluster;
```

As I'm using symfony 1.4 and doctrine 1.2, I want to get it right by adding a method to Class a with the name maxCluster():

```
class A extends BaseA{

  ..

  public function maxCluster(){
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('MAX(b.cluster)')->from('B b')->where('b.a_id = ?', $this->getId())->groupBy('b.cluster');
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('A')->execute($q);
  }
}
```

When doing this, I get the following error message:

```
A query with the name A/SELECT MAX(b.cluster) FROM B b WHERE b.a_id = ? GROUP BY b.cluster does not exist.
```

I think the solution should be not that complicated, I'm just stuck right now.

Thanks for any help,
Sebastian

EDIT: I got a hint, so know the code of the maxCluster-function looks like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('MAX(b.cluster) AS maxCluster')->from('B b')->where('b.a_id = ?', $this->getId())->;
$result = $q->fetchOne();
return $result->maxCluster;
```

The question for me right now is: Is this the best way? I'm confused that fetchOne returns a picture-array. I wouldn't expect such a behaviour because I select one int and not objects. Maybe anyone can point out what best pratice for such queries is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute methon relative to getTable is used to execute named queries, have a look at the [doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language%3anamed-queries/en) to find more if you want to use them.

Or you can use `return $q->execute()` to return the result of the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see my edit above: It's working now, but I'm not happy with it.

Comment: try using a different hydration mode: `return $q->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR)`